# Regex for opening hours (days - time)

Tags: php, regex, forms

I have a form input where users can fill out the opening hours of their restaurant (for storage in a database) in the following format:

```
Fri 12-02, Sat 15-03
```

and I need a regex to validate their inputs.

**Update from comments:**
The pattern is:
`3 character DayOfWeek`, `[space]`, `the opening hour (24 hour)`, `[hyphen]`, `the closing hour (24 hour)`

> Well, it's the openings hours in days ('Fri') and time ('12-02' as in 12:00 until 02:00). It should reject anything that doesn't follow the same pattern ideally. So

Comment: What format is that? What should it match? What should it reject?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to validate that the first three characters are in - Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun - the 5th and 6th characters are between 00 and 24, the 7th character is a '-' and the 8th and 9th characters are between 00 and 24?

Comment: Well, it's the openings hours in days ('Fri') and time ('12-02' as in 12:00 until 02:00). It should reject anything that doesn't follow the same pattern ideally. So

Comment: Brian: Yes, exactly =) Although I'll be satisified with validating the three letters for weekdays as nothing but letters.

Comment: **Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values.** Find a likely string with the regex, then check its numeric value in whatever your host language is (PHP, whatever).

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Comment: **Show us what you've tried so far.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what didn't work.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 2):

Regex with named patterns:

`/(?P<day>Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)(?:-(?P<today>Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun))?\s+(?P<from>(?<=\s)(?:(?:2[0-3])|(?:[01]?[0-9]))(?:\:[0-5][0-9])?)-(?P<till>(?<=-)(?:(?:2[0-3])|(?:[01]?[0-9]))(?:\:[0-5][0-9])?)/g`

http://regex101.com/r/cP8rQ4

It matches all these: "Fri 12-02, Sat 15:30-03, Mon 12-02, Mon 15-03, Mon-Thu 8:30-16:45" and gives you an array with named keys (day, today, from, till). 
You must use `preg_match_all` with `PREG_SET_ORDER` for this.

Example output:

```
    array(
      array(
        'day' => 'Fri',
        'from' => '12',
        'till' => '02'
      ), array(
        'day' => 'Sat',
        'from' => '15:30',
        'till' => '03'
      ), array(
        'day' => 'Mon',
        'from' => '12',
        'till' => '02'
      ), array(
        'day' => 'Mon',
        'from' => '15',
        'till' => '03'
      ), array(
        'day' => 'Mon',
        'today' => 'Thu',
        'from' => '8:30',
        'till' => '16:45'
      )
    );
```

At least im not sure if it is `PREG_SET_ORDER` or `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` just try it.

Comment: `PREG_SET_ORDER` is the flag for the array output you show

Answer (score 1):

Only match `3 letter days`, then a  `[space]`  then `24hour time` then `-` then `24hour time`

```
(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)\s([2][0-4]|[0-1][0-9])-([2][0-4]|[0-1][0-9])
```

Match:

```
Fri 12-12
Sat 23-22
```

Will not match:

```
Jpg 12-12
Sat 25-22
```

Answer (score 0):

Common regexp will be

```
/^[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s\d\d-\d\d/
```

Example in JavaScript: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/svcA3/1/)**

Same pattern in PHP: **[phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zk6-egz)**

Comment: @user2705219, assuming it's the only value in your input, I added `^` that means "beginning of string"

Answer (score 0):

What's valid and invalid btw?

Also, what fields are we looking at? Text fields?

My regex:

```
/[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/
```

It only validates for the numeric part (i.e. 12-02) and Fri, could be on a drop down menu.

If not, `/[A-Z][a-z]{2} [0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/`...

Note that this does not validate the actual numeric time value, it only validates the format against the format of your example.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to write a regular expression that will *correctly* validate all the possible date formats. Leave the job to a date parser, which was written for exactly this purpose. Here's how you would use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class to accomplish this:

```
function customValidate($str, $format='D d-m')
{
    // explode the string, remove whitespace
    list($date1,$date2) = array_map('trim', explode(',', $str));

    // parse them into DateTime objects
    $d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date1);
    $d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date2);

    // check if they're valid
    $d1f = $d1->format($format) == $date1;
    $d2f = $d2->format($format) == $date2;

    // return the boolean result
    return $d1 && $d2 && $d1f && $d2f;
}
```

Comment: That'll probably work better than my initial idea =) Thanks!